# Sulu CMS 2.0: How to use jexl in Category Selection?

Tags: sulu

Is there somewhere a bit of documentation how to write jexl for the `category_selection` Content Type? The [current 2.0 documentation](https://docs.sulu.io/en/2.0/reference/content-types/category_selection.html) is a bit thin in this topic.

I tried blindly:

```xml
<property name="authors" type="category_selection">
   <meta>
      <title lang="de">Autor</title>
      <title lang="en">Author</title>
   </meta>

   <params>
      <param name="item_disabled_condition" value="parent.key == 'authors'"/>
   </params>
</property>
```

But it does not even throw an error ;).

What I try to do is, to allow only selection of children of a certain sub category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done it almost correctly, the only problem is that the available values are exactly what the API returns. And in the case of categories, the `parent` key refers to the ID of the parent. And you don't get an error because you can access the `key` attribute on a number, the only problem is that it will be `undefined`.

So what you can do is the following:

```xml
<property name="authors" type="category_selection">
   <meta>
      <title lang="de">Autor</title>
      <title lang="en">Author</title>
   </meta>

   <params>
      <param name="item_disabled_condition" value="parent == 1"/>
   </params>
</property>
```

I know that this is not really nice, because you have to put a database ID into a configuration, but that's the only way I see that currently working... If `parent.key` should work, we would have to adjust the API.

Currently a category json returned by `/admin/api/categories` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "Cat Name", // name in the selected language
  "id": 6,
  "depth": 2, // depth in the tree
  "parent": 2, // id of the parent
  "locale": "de",
  "defaultLocale": "de",
  "lft": 5,
  "rgt": 6,
  "hasChildren": false
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot for this! I'll check it out. Is there a way to see or debug what values are available? Also an issue with database id's is, that they will be different between development, staging and live systems. I will try a bit and see if I can get it to work with multiple database ids for the multipe systems.

Comment: But yes, access to the key would make it imho much more useful :)

Comment: Hm, the way I check which values is available, is that I have a look at the request loading the items in the network tab of the browser's dev tools... Not very elegant, I know. But I could e.g. also imagine to log every check done by the `item_disabled_condition` to the console. I guess that would help, although you would still have to know where to look...

Comment: Ok, so one year later I can confirm it actually works. But it is a pitty, that there is no way to actualy savely accross multiple instalations exclude or filter whole category trees.